# Why new products take so long to show on frontend

Tags: magento2, php, products, reindex

The products we add in Magento 2 take too long to show on frontend, specifically 24 hours give or take before they start to show. Is this a php or index issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are your indexers updated on save or on schedule? It looks like they are sent on schedule.
You can run the following command to check the mode:

```bash
bin/magento indexer:show-mode
```

If the mode of indexers is set to 'Update by Schedule', like:
[image]

You need to change it to 'Update on Save', using the following command:

```bash
bin/magento indexer:set-mode realtime
```

The output of the command should be something like this:
[image]